# Unable to get Line Chart tooltip on ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

i want to create multi line chart using ChartJS. multi line chart is working fine. but tool-tip only i am getting problem. please check below code and image.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            spanGaps: false,
        },
      {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [40, 59, 80, 100, 56, 80, 70],
            spanGaps: false,
        }
    ]
};

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

[image]

January month i have two data ["My first dataset":65, "My Second Dataset": 40] so tool-tip showing correctly but in march month i have two data ["My first dataset":80, "My Second Dataset": 80] but tool-tip showing only "My First dataset"  value only so i m not able to find "My Second Dataset" value.

Comment: I am use chatJs 2.1.x and the tooltips can show both when the data is same, and I have try to use 2.2.x cdn cover my charJs file, i just found seems they change the tooltips style, if you can't not lower your version, maybe you have to custom your tooltips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this. now its working fine

```
options: {
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label'
                }
         }
```